# jQuery/JavaScript: Trigger when preloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, background-image, preload

jQuery has the .ready() function, but I am unsure whether this is what I need:

I set a default background image in CSS (imange 1 out of 4), once document is loaded (images and all, not only DOM); I want to start preloading background image 2 out of 4. Once that is loaded, I want to fade image 1 into image 2. Then I want to preload the next image (3 out of 4), once that is loaded, I want to fade from background image 2 into image 3, and finally preload image 4. Once image 4 is loaded, i would like to fade image 3 into image 4. After that, I want to cycle between the images with a set time interval.

What strategy would I use to solve this? .load() function?

Thank you for your time.

Kind regards,
Marius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Jquery.ready()` or better yet `$()` will trigger once the last page element is successfully loaded. From there you can proceed to run a chain of methods, each method triggering the next in a callback passed to it.

Comment: The animations are asynchronous and it throws a lot of people. This suggestion is a good one.

Comment: I know about this, but this is not what I want. Each background image will be fairly big, therefore I'd prefer to do it the way I suggested: Load the first one, then fade in to the next one once it is loaded, not wait untill all of them is loaded.M

Comment: That is the starting point next you would bind to the `.load` event of the images. http://api.jquery.com/load-event/